# Initialize a template struct at definition

Tags: c++, templates, struct, template-specialization

I'm not sure if the topic quite matches what I am looking for, but here it is basically:

I can do this:

```
struct something {
    int d;
} somethingType;
```

But why can't I do this?

```
template <bool T>
struct somethingelse {
    int d;
}<true> somethingelseType;
```

If it is possible to do the second one, what will be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Why would you want to take pictures of Saturn?

Comment: @AlanStokes I did it because I did not want to declare it in main. But I tried the first one and when it worked and I decided to try to second one and that is where I got compiler issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could, grammatically, but it's forbidden by additional restrictions:

[temp]/1

> A *template* defines a family of classes or functions or an alias for a family of types.
>
> *template-declaration:*
>        `template <` *template-parameter-list* `>` *declaration*
>
> *template-parameter-list:*
>        *template-parameter*
>        *template-parameter-list* `,` *template-parameter*
>
> [...]
>
> The *declaration* in a *template-declaration* shall
>
> - declare or define a function or a class, or
> - define a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, or a static data member of a class template or of a class nested within a class template, or
> - define a member template of a class or class template, or
> - be an *alias-declaration*.

A declaration (the top-level grammatical construct) can be a *template-declaration*, so these rules *directly* apply to the declaration.

On the other hand (i.e. for non-template classes), a *declaration* can also be a *block-declaration* [dcl.dcl]/1, which can be a *simple-declaration*, which can contain a *decl-specifier-seq* which can contain a *type-specifier* [dcl.type]/1 which can be a *class-specifier* which can declare a class o.O and using this *type-specifier* you could declare a variable:

(resolving one construct per line into its (possible) components)

```
declaration
block-declaration
simple-declaration
decl-specifier-seqopt                    init-declarator-listopt ;
type-secifier                           init-declarator-listopt ;
class-specifier                         init-declarator-listopt ;
class-head { member-specificationopt }   init-declarator-listopt ;
class-head { member-specificationopt }   init-declarator ;
class-head { member-specificationopt }   declarator initializeropt ;
class-head { member-specificationopt }   ptr-declarator ;
class-head { member-specificationopt }   noptr-declarator ;
class-head { member-specificationopt }   declarator-id attribute-specifier-seqopt ;
class-head { member-specificationopt }   ...opt id-expression ;
```

Which now matches, say, `struct something { int d; } somethingType;`

But that would be a declaration of a variable, which is not allowed for the template case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.

You can follow a struct by object names (according to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/), not by template parameters.

Comment: I’m not saying this answer is wrong (I’m not sure), but cplusplus.com is generally not a reliable source. Use cppreference.com, or better yet the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

A `type-specifier` can be

- `trailing-type-specifier`
- `class-specifier`
- `enum-specifier`

As you can see, `template-declaration` is not included, hence what you are looking for doesn't exist (directly)

See online version of C++11 grammar rules hyperlinked: http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#type-specifier